# when process dialog is being displayed, doInBackground() is not being executed

Tags: android

I'm trying to display process dialog, it is being showed as expected, but when it is being showed, doInBackground() is not being executed, when I press on screen of emulator, then doInBackground() starts executing again.

This is my AsyncTask class:

```
public class FetchEmployeeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Employee> >   {

private CaptureActivity activity;
//private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public FetchEmployeeAsyncTask(CaptureActivity nextActivity) {
    this.activity = nextActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    /*progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Fetching Employees!!");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.show();*/
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Employee> doInBackground(String... url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated methoVoidd stub

    ArrayList<Employee> employees = null;
    for(String employeeUrl : url){
        employees = fetch(employeeUrl);
    }
    return employees;
}

private ArrayList<Employee> fetch(String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = null;
    String response = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        employees = EmployeeXMLParser.employeeParser(response);
        System.out.println("Size in fetch "+employees.size());

        //System.out.println("Employee Name :: " + employees.get(0).getFirstName() + " " + employees.get(0).getLastName());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /*catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error parsing the response :: " + response);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    return employees;
}



@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Employee> employees){
    super.onPostExecute(employees);

    System.out.println("in post execxute "+employees.size());
    //progressDialog.dismiss(); 
    activity.showEmployees(employees);


}
```

}

I'm calling AsyncTask in this activity class:

```
public class CaptureActivity extends Activity {


private String url = "http://192.168.2.223:8680/capture/clientRequest.do?r=employeeList&cid=0";

FetchEmployeeAsyncTask employeeAsyncTask;

private ArrayList<Employee> employees = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("");


     employeeAsyncTask = new FetchEmployeeAsyncTask(this);

     employeeAsyncTask.execute(new String[] {url});

    System.out.println("Status "+employeeAsyncTask.getStatus());


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);

}
```

Comment: how you are executing AsyncTask?

Comment: move setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture); line before starting AsyncTask

Comment: Prosper...same result!!

Comment: also change  `employeeAsyncTask.execute(new String[] {url});` to  `employeeAsyncTask.execute(url);`

Comment: no change in the behavior!!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here? are you trying to get some values from the database if so check the assignment of the url if you are passing the value correctly.

Also please try explaining your problem in detail and paste some more code.

Comment: I'm hitting a web application n fetching the response and trying to process it, if I comment out process dialog, its working fine..else process dialog is being showed with out running doInBackground()..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  protected void onPreExecute() {

   progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(currentActivity.this, "",
                "Message Here", true);
    }
   protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

   dialog.dismiss();

   }
```

Comment: This is a basic method to running the process dialog but i don't know your exact problem. so can you explain clearly?..

Comment: process dialog keeps on displaying, and code in doInBackground() is not being executed until I cancel process dialog. This is the problem I'm facing.